# Get the value of one cell based on the value of another

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

Edited with additional context:

Embedded in a LibreOffice-5 Calc spreadsheet I have a two column array where one column contains dates and the other column values.  I wish to select the row based on the MAX date found in a range and return that value in one cell elsewhere on the spreadsheet together with the adjacent cell's value in a separate cell elsewhere on the spreadsheet.

The way I conceive this is that the MAX(X30:X40) returns the most recent date.  I also want to derive from this result the address of the adjacent cell (Y?) and return that value as well.  For example given:

```
          X        Y
30
31    20011231    205
32    20110106    171
33    20120715    321
34    20151031    165
35
36
```

and elsewhere on the same sheet this:

```
          A        B
15
```

I wish cell `A15` initially to display `20151031` (X34) and `B15` to display `165` (Y34).  If later someone updates the empty cell `X35` with `20160101` and cell `Y35` with `37` then I wish cells `A15` and `B15` to recalculate to show`20160101` and `37` respectively.

How is this done if it is at all possible?

Comment: I don't think I follow you correctly... would a `VLOOKUP` solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is as follows:

Given:

```
          X          Y
29    Heading 1  Heading 2
30
31    20011231      205
32    20110106      171
33    20120715      321
34    20151031      165
35
36
```

Then this gives the desired result:

```
          A                B
14    Heading 1        Heading 2
15    =MAXA(X29:X36)   =DGET(X29:Y36,"Heading 2",A14:B15)
```

And this also works:

```
          A                B
14    Heading 1        Heading 2
15    =MAXA(X29:X36)   =DGET(X29:Y36,Y29,A14:B15)
```